# socat - problems with logfile to tcp binding

Tags: socat

I have a question to using socat in a special situation. I have a logfile on a system e.g. /var/log/logfile.log and I want to do a binding from the logfile to a tcp (telnet) connection.

So when I start a telnet to the system I will see new entries in the logfile.

I try this:

```
sudo socat -v tcp-l:4712,reuseaddr,fork file:"/var/lser2net/ser2net.log",nonblock,
```

That works but even when a new entry will write in the logfile, I got the whole logfile via telnet again.

I only need new lines, not the whole logfile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [tail](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tail&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en) command:

1. To see the last 10 lines and then all new ones until the connection is closed:

`socat -v tcp-l:4712,reuseaddr,fork exec:"tail -f -n10 /var/lser2net/ser2net.log"`

2. To see only the last 10 lines:

`socat -v tcp-l:4712,reuseaddr,fork exec:"tail -n10 /var/lser2net/ser2net.log"`

3. To see only new lines until the connection is closed:

`socat -v tcp-l:4712,reuseaddr,fork exec:"tail -f -n0 /var/lser2net/ser2net.log"`

Good luck!